# Complexity and fast Solution for "probing subset problem"?

Tags: optimization, computational-complexity

I have stumbled across a problem in my free time to which I am struggling to find a fast solution to. It came up when solving systems of equations and can be stated as follows:

Suppose you have a set $S=\{1,…,n\}$ and an unknown but nonempty set of subsets of $S$, $B$. That is, $\forall b \in B, b \subseteq S$. Nothing else about $B$ is known.

Edit: Example: If $S=\{1,2,3,4\}$, then $B$ could for example be $B=\{\{1\}, \{1,2\}, \{3,4\}, \{1,2,3,4\}\}$

Now define a "probe" as an operation, where you give a subset of $S$ to some function and it returns whether it is the superset of some $b \in B$.

The first problem: *only using probes, find some element of $B$.*

The second problem: *only using probes, find the smallest element of $B$.*

For the first problem, finding an algorithm, even an $O(n)$ one (in terms of number of probes) is quite straightforward: Let $A$ be the starting set with $A = S$, then, for each number  $p \in \{1,…,n\}$, probe $A\backslash p$ . If the probe succeeds, set $A \leftarrow A \backslash p$. Else, continue. After doing this for all $p \in \{1,…,n\}$, it is guarenteed that $A \in B$.

The second problem is much more difficult to solve and I didn't manage to find any even "close to fast" algorithm for it.

I found nothing about it online.
I also tried phrasing it as a binary optimization problem in $n$ Dimensions, where the size of the set is optimized, but that didn't get me far.

It relates indirectly to solving a specific limited system of equations, specifically, how many equations can be removed until no variable can be fixed.

My questions are: Is this problem known under another name? Can it be transformed into a more useful/known problem? If yes, is there a faster algorithm for the first problem? And is there a remotely fast (possibly sub-$O(2^n)$) algorithm for the second question?

Comment: To solve the second problem, can't you just probe, in order, $A_i := \{ x \in S \mid x \leq i \}$?  The first instance of $A_i$ that returns a positive result is your winner.

Comment: Oh yeah, going backward, I missed that. That is a valid, and often fast solution. Good find! (Technically it's still $O(2^n)$, but given that $B$ is pretty much entirely unknown, I doubt there is a faster algorithm.)

Comment: @RobertShore How is your algorithm supposed to go? If the first positive result is on, say, $A_5=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, then what?

Comment: @Milten Then $5$ is the least element of $B$.

Comment: If it's faster, just define $A_i= \{ i \}$.

Comment: @RobertShore But that only works if $B$ contains a singleton. $B$ is a set of sets, no? I read the problem as finding the set $b\in B$ of least cardinality

Comment: @Milten $B$ is clearly defined as a subset of $S$, not a subset of $\mathscr P(S)$.

Comment: @RobertShore I disagree. Sese Mueller, can you clarify then? “nonempty set of subset[s?] of $S$, $B$. That is, $\forall b\in B, b\subseteq S$”. An element of $B$ is stated as a subset of $S$. Also consistent with the use of “superset”

Comment: @Milten, yes, $B$ is a set of sets. Each element of $B$ is a subset of $S$, so if $S=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, then $B$ could be $B=\{\{1,2,3\},\{3,4,5\}\}$.